# Ubuntu Mate login screen won't go away

Tags: login, mate

I installed Mate Desktop UI on my VM couple days ago. I didn't like it and I removed it, but the login screen doesn't seem to go away. I don't mind it, but now when I input the password, it doesn't log me in anymore. I even tried to go to console using Ctrl+Alt+F2 to reinstall ubuntu desktop and remove all Mate packages but I cant resolve it.

Comment: You've not provided any OS & release details; however when you install then remove a desktop; some changes are up to you to reverse (eg. changes to `plymouth` wallpaper is on you, if you selected a different DM that's again for you to change etc...)  It's not related to packages; but effects of your commands used to install for your *unstated* OS & release.  If you're having a *login loop* issue; I'd login via text terminal & ensure you have space available in $HOME or your user directory - a common issue on package changes; otherwise I'd check what you actually removed

Comment: Mate isn't Ubuntu. This is AskUbuntu.

Comment: FYI: This box had `ubuntu-mate-desktop` installed for many cycles, but my box ran out of disk space, so removing it was an easy fix for me to get around lack of space issues.. It was removed; I of course read what packages would be removed; to ensure no issues on the rest of my system would occur (*and re-installed any packages that were removed that I'd miss*) and my system kept running. I'd not switched my DM to MATE's so didn't need to reverse that; had already changed my `plymouth` so as to not show Ubuntu-MATE's ... effects were none..  I'll add it back when I can (ie. I have disk space)